# Cron is running, but not running

Tags: drupal, error, cron

I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.9 on Drupal 7.50.  Drupal's cron is running fine every 3 hours, using Drupal's built-in scheduler.  I can also run cron successfully manually.

However, I still get the famous error message in CiviCRM saying that cron has never run:

[image]

What specifically in the database is this check looking for, and what's supposed to be creating that?  Is this likely to be a problem with cron actually not running, or a problem with *detecting* whether it's run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this very detailed answer on a different SE site by Chris:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136722/drupal-7-cron-does-not-run-civicrm-scheduled-jobs

Comment: Oh - so Civi's cron has never been triggered by Drupal's cron?  I thought that was the default setup, apparently I haven't been running cron for the last 7 years. =(

Comment: Note that you can run a cron to cal a specific CiviCRM job by itself as well - perhaps you've been doing that?

Comment: Thanks @KarinG, I haven't been doing that either though.  Glad this warning got added so I could clean up my act.

Comment: You're all set then! Best!